# (Fixed) Vercel Django Deployment Error : 500: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR. Unable to import module 'backend.settings'

Tags: python, html, django, deployment, vercel

I have created a Django Project which I wanna use as backend for my React project. In the root of the project there are two folders : `backend` for django and `frontends` for react. Also I have provided a screenshot of the directory tree of my project: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFkYG.png)

I added `requirements.txt` and `vercel.json` with all required stuff below is the code snippets for both. Also I have added vercel to allowed domains according to the documentation. But when I deploy  the app through GitHub in vercel, deployment process finishes but when I visit the website I get `500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR` which further says 'FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED'

So then I go to vercel and check Runtime Logs and I get to see the following error printed multiple times:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'vc__handler__python': No module named 'backend.settings'
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

So the error is not probably due to missing dependencies in `requirements.txt` but with the import error of my project files. In this case the `settings.py`. I don't really understand what's causing the import error since I gave correct paths of `wsgi.py` in `vercel.json`

`requirements.txt`

```
asgiref==3.6.0
Django==4.2
djangorestframework==3.14.0
python-dotenv==1.0.0
pytz==2023.3
sqlparse==0.4.3
tzdata==2023.3
```

`vercel.json`

```
{
    "builds": [{
        "src": "backend/backend/wsgi.py",
        "use": "@vercel/python",
        "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb", "runtime": "python3.9" }
    }],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "backend/backend/wsgi.py"
        }
    ]
}
```

`wsgi.py`

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "backend.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()

app = application
```

Tried to deploy the project through GitHub but faced ERRORS instead of successful deployment.

> **FIX I FOUND :**

Just don't create separate folders for backend and frontend put both django files and react files in same root folder and configure both accordingly. I combined the folders and made some changes in vercel.json file and the view was visible in vercel with no errors. For more info on configuration you can check out my project implementing this configuration. [GitHub Project Link](https://github.com/Shagnikpaul/helios-weather-bot-website)

Comment: Not yet still searching for more solutions :P

Comment: Kinda found a fix, just don't create a separate for backend and frontend put both django files and react files in same root folder and configure both accordingly. I combined the folders and made some changes in vercel.json file and the view was visible in vercel with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone here in the future, this is caused by django importing modules from the backend path, while vercel imports everything from your base directory. A hacky way to fix this without reorganizing your folders is to add a snippet which includes your backend folder in your sys paths.

First, make sure to update your .env file to set an env variable to 'dev' locally, and 'production' in Vercel.

Then, in your wsgi.py file:

```
if os.environ.get('ENV') == 'production':
    sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```